# Azure functions PowerShell Hash keys

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-functions

Trying to expose via API some internal azure details I found that I'm unable to select a particular tag from a ResourceGroup object in a Powershell Azure function.

This snippet works in standard PowerShell but produces no output in a function.

```
$rgs = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup

$output = @()

foreach($rg in $rgs) {
    $output += $rg.Tags.owner
}

Out-File -Encoding Ascii -FilePath $res -inputObject ($output | ConvertTo-Json)
```

If I only select the tags (no particular Keys) I can see all the information there, but doing `Tags.owner`, `Tags['owner']` gives no output. If I do 
 `Tags.Item('owner')` I also get an exception! *Cannot convert argument "index", with value: "owner", for "get_Item" to type "System.Int32"*

How can hash tables be used inside a PowerShell Azure function?

Comment: have you tried stepping through your code in a debugger like ISE/VSCode? your code works when i try it on my test groups.

Comment: I'm unable to attach the remote debugger in VScode. Anyway  I double cheked it and something like `$output = $rgs[0].Tags` works while `$output = $rgs[0].Tags.owner` gives no error but no result. The same works in standard PS.